# AWS Lambda - Combine multiple CSV files from S3 into one file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to understand and learn how to get all my files from the specific bucket into one csv file. I have the files that are like logs and are always in the same format and are kept in the same bucket. I have this code to access them and read them:

```
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    x = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    print(x)
```

It does print them with separation between specific files and also column headers.

The question I have got is, how can I modify my loop to get them into just one csv file?

Comment: write x into a file instead... or just call it and redirect the output to a file (ie `$ python my_script.py > output.csv`

Comment: One more question, how can I get x into the data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a file in `/tmp/` and `write` the contents of each object into that file.

Then, when all files have been read, **upload the file** (or do whatever you want to do with it).

```py
output = open('/tmp/outfile.txt', 'w')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    output.write(obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
    
output.close
```

Please note that there is a limit of 512MB in the `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: Thank you again. Do you know how to remove duplicates after all files are combined? I have this code but as column headers are duplicates as well, they are removed. I just want to keep the very first row not changed? My additional loop `out  = open('/tmp/outfile.txt', 'w' for line in lines_set: out.write(line) out.close`

Comment: You could skip-over the first line for every file except the first line. Use a variable to remember whether it is the first file. It's just a matter of reading the file per-line. See: [Read a file line by line in Python - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/)

Comment: Thanks again John! Do you know how can I actually change that object to the dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean by "change that object to the dataframe"?

Comment: What I meant it the object x from my initial code to be read as the data frame. I just need to do some cleaning before it goes back to S3.